# Set attribute to all types in XML Schema

Tags: xsd, attributes

I store settings of my script in `XML` document. The script is multiplatform but some of its settings are not. I created proper attribute in my `XSD` file. It decides to which system is the setting.

```
<xs:attribute name="system" use="optional" default="none">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="none"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="windows"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="unix"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

A sample `XML` file looks like below. (Don't read too carefully. It's just an example.)

```
<root>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <path system="windows">%appdata%\Bar</path>
    <path system="unix">~/Bar/</path>
    <foo system="unix">
        <bar>baz</bar>
        <!-- more elements -->
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <bar system="windows">baz</bar>
        <!-- more elements -->
    </foo>
</root>
```

The problem is I need possibility to add attribute `system` to each element of my `XML`. At this moment I can't simply write:

```
<xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
```

Instead that I have to write:

```
<xs:element name="path">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="system"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

(I know that I can define complex type before and use it multiple times.) It is very expanded `XSD` and I have a lot of my own types in it. Many of them are used in one place only. Actually I set attribute `system` to each type in my `XSD` but it takes a lot of space and is not very readable.

**Is it possible to set attribute to *all* types in `XSD`?**

Comment: In xsd1.0, it is not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu It can be xsd1.1.

Comment: In XSD 1.1 you can use the `defaultAttributes attribute in <schema>` to add a list of attributes that all complex element must have. This can be overrided using the _ defaultAttributesApply _ attribute in complex types. Unfortunately this does not apply to simpleTypes, but maybe you can use a workaround such as a complextype with no content using an assertion. [See this.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#ch_attrdecl)

Comment: @sergioFC "this does not apply to simpleTypes" - This makes sense. I realized now that simpleTypes can be use in attributes, so they cannot require attributes. I can wrap they in complexTypes. Please, write this as answer so I could up-vote you.

Comment: Thanks but this info is now present in user kjhughes answer that have added another option. There is no need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options for globally defining a common attribute to be used in many locations include:

- Have all types derive from a common type that includes the attribute.
- Use `xs:attribute/@ref`, which you've already mentioned.
- Use `xs:attributeGroup/@ref`, which would allow you to reference multiple
  commonly declared attributes collectively.  **Update**: In XSD 1.1, a [default attribute
  group can be specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#ch_attrdecl) via `defaultAttributes` on the `xs:schema` element that applies to all
  complex type definitions.  *Thanks to @sergioFC for this good idea.*
- Use `xs:any` element, and then (in XSD 1.1) `xs:assert` about the attribute, but
  then you lose most of the normal element and attribute declaration
  facilities due to `xs:any`'s intrinsic leniency.

Other than such indirect options, there is no mechanism in XSD for centrally stating that an attribute may/must be present on all elements.

Comment: Good answer, I would add that this can be used in addition with defaultAttributes attribute I've mentioned in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235281/set-attribute-to-all-types-in-xml-schema#comment50678525_31235281)

Comment: I accepted this answer because `defaultAttributes` seems to be right solution and I don't expect the better one. However, I can't find any `XML` validator which supports `XSD 1.1` :(