# Defining a XML element for all nodes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using XSD to define a XML schema and I need to have the following element as a possible child element of any other element in the document.

```
<include path="include1.xml"/>
```

Is there an elegant way of defining this? I don't want to define `include` as a child element for each of the elements already defined within the XSD.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235281/set-attribute-to-all-types-in-xml-schema) using default attributes instead of default elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use XML processing instructions for this purpose, since using a XML element would violate the [Unique Particle Attribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution) rule. I replaced XML element `<include path="include1.xml">` with the following processing instruction.

```
<?include include1.xml?>
```

The two related posts can help resolve similar issues:

1. [XSD: Allow any unknown element in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741978/xsd-allow-any-unknown-element-in-any-order)
2. [XSD: Allow elements from different namespace anywhere in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178259/xsd-allow-elements-from-different-namespace-anywhere-in-a-sequence)